# How do iphone backup extraction programs work?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

There are a plethora of applications (usually expensive ones) that can extract a backup file of an iphone's data.
(examples: [drfone](https://drfone.wondershare.com/),  [anytrans](https://www.imobie.com/anytrans/))

How are these apps actually accessing the iphone's file system, allowing them to extract a backup database file?

No matter how hard I look for the answer, I'm just pointed to these apps. How can any user extract a backup file from a usb-connected iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps usually just initiate a backup themselves first, having their own implementation of the iOS backup protocol (or using libimobiledevice libraries). So, they're not really directly accessing the iOS filesystem via USB, they're making a backup in their own app data folder, and then accessing that. (I work on iOS backup tools - not the ones you mentioned - and this slight of hand from other tools bugs me ;))

> How can any user extract a backup file from a usb-connected iphone?

Are you asking about how to get to one of the files in your backup, or how to download the files from the iPhone (aka acting like a backup client)? If you want to take your own backups without iTunes, libimobiledevice is your best bet. https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. is this the type of tool that those 'pay to use' backup programs are using?

i'm just wondering why it's been so hard to find resources; all i can find are those pay to use programs.